# Is the phrase "slot machine" 老虎机 the same in different Chinese dialects?

Tags: mandarin, cantonese, hakka

Just wondering whether the phrase 老虎机 (slot machine) sounds and is written the same in all Chinese dialects, such as:

Mandarin, 
Wu Chinese, 
Min Chinese, 
Cantonese, 
Jin Chinese, 
Xiang  Chinese, 
Hakka Chinese and 
Gan Chinese.

Are there any slang phrases to say "slots", "slot machine", "one armed bandit"?

http://slotmachine77.com/chinese-slot-machine

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: In Standard Chinese it is also known as 角子机.

Comment: And 拉霸机 http://www.tkb518.com/jiqiaocelue/laohujiyingqianjiqiao/2011/0405/7040.html

Comment: In Cantonese, yes, it is 老虎機.

Comment: In Taiwan, it is 吃角子老虎.

Answer (score 2):

It is written the same in basically every dialect of Chinese, but pronounced in a very wide variety of ways. It is called "tiger machine" because it, indeed, eats up your cash :P

Answer (score 0):

I think you probably can call it "赌博机". It is not a slang but people would understand.